# An elegant way to get hashtags out of a string in Python?

Tags: python, string, list-comprehension, hashtag

I'm looking for a clean way to get a set (list, array, whatever) of words starting with `#` inside a given string.

In C#, I would write

```
var hashtags = input
    .Split (' ')
    .Where (s => s[0] == '#')
    .Select (s => s.Substring (1))
    .Distinct ();
```

What is comparatively elegant code to do this in Python?

**EDIT**

Sample input: `"Hey guys! #stackoverflow really #rocks #rocks #announcement"`
Expected output: `["stackoverflow", "rocks", "announcement"]`

Comment: Now that you added `.Distinct()` - does it have to be the same order as in the input or can it be an unordered set? The latter is a much easier and faster way to filter out duplicates.

Comment: @delnan: Unordered set is fine.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

With [@inspectorG4dget's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6331497/an-elegant-way-to-get-hashtags-out-of-a-string-in-python/6331563#6331563), if you want no duplicates, you can use set comprehensions instead of list comprehensions.

```
>>> tags="Hey guys! #stackoverflow really #rocks #rocks #announcement"
>>> {tag.strip("#") for tag in tags.split() if tag.startswith("#")}
set(['announcement', 'rocks', 'stackoverflow'])
```

Note that `{ }` syntax for set comprehensions only works starting with Python 2.7.
If you're working with older versions, feed list comprehension (`[ ]`) output to `set` function as [suggested by @Bertrand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6331497/an-elegant-way-to-get-hashtags-out-of-a-string-in-python/6331560#6331560).

Comment: There is a typo in my name: it's inspectorG4dget. You have a '5' instead of a '4'

Comment: @inspectorG4dget , sorry, didn't noticed. And I learned I should link it.

Comment: One thing to add to this, if anyone is working with instagram etc... the tags are contained in a caption and don't necessarily need spaces between them. IE the caption  `#washington#westcoasts#florida`  Would evaluate to `['washington#westcoasts#florida']` 
---------------------------------------------------
My workaround:
`{ tag.strip(" #") for tag in tags.replace('#',' #').split() if tag.startswith(" #") }`

Comment: @duality: thanks, while your solution doesn't work directly, there's a small fix - then it works `{tag.strip("#") for tag in tags.replace('#',' #').split() if tag.startswith("#")}`

Answer (score 15):

```
[i[1:] for i in line.split() if i.startswith("#")]
```

This version will get rid of any empty strings (as I have read such concerns in the comments) and strings that are only `"#"`. Also, as in [Bertrand Marron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/212384/bertrand-marron)'s code, it's better to turn this into a set as follows (to avoid duplicates and for O(1) lookup time):

```
set([i[1:] for i in line.split() if i.startswith("#")])
```

Comment: +1 for .startswith.  Here it doesn't matter, but it handles the case of empty strings and generalizes nicely to any length, and so is a good habit to get into.

Comment: @gaearon: `somestr.split()` wont, it strips all extra whitespace. `'a'.split('a')` will.

Comment: @gaearon: It may return an empty list if the string is empty or contains only whitespace. The strings in that list won't be empty if `.split()` is called, but may be if an explicit seperator is given and the string contains two of those without anything else in between. See [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).

Comment: all `split()` based methods have the same issues: tags dont have to be separated by whitespace only: `#tag1,#tag2`.  also please note that `set()` is unordered and  the order of the final list may change, maybe important, maybe not.

Answer (score 10):

the `findall` method of [regular expression objects](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) can get them all at once:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "this #is a #string with several #hashtags"
>>> pat = re.compile(r"#(\w+)")
>>> pat.findall(s)
['is', 'string', 'hashtags']
>>>
```

Answer (score 8):

I'd say

```
hashtags = [word[1:] for word in input.split() if word[0] == '#']
```

Edit: this will create a set without any duplicates.

```
set(hashtags)
```

Comment: You beat me to it by 8 seconds

Answer (score 1):

Another option is regEx:

```
import re

inputLine = "Hey guys! #stackoverflow really #rocks #rocks #announcement"

re.findall(r'(?i)\#\w+', inputLine) # will includes #
re.findall(r'(?i)(?<=\#)\w+', inputLine) # will not include #
```

Comment: Good, but I wanted something more easily readable than regexes.

Answer (score 1):

there are some problems with the answers presented here.

1. {tag.strip("#") for tag in tags.split() if tag.startswith("#")}

   [i[1:] for i in line.split() if i.startswith("#")]

wont works if you have hashtag like '#one#two#'

2 `re.compile(r"#(\w+)")` wont work for many unicode languages (even using re.UNICODE)

i had seen more ways to extract hashtag, but found non of them answering on all cases

so i wrote some small python code to handle most of the cases. it works for me.

```
def get_hashtagslist(string):
    ret = []
    s=''
    hashtag = False
    for char in string:
        if char=='#':
            hashtag = True
            if s:
                ret.append(s)
                s=''           
            continue

        # take only the prefix of the hastag in case contain one of this chars (like on:  '#happy,but i..' it will takes only 'happy'  )
        if hashtag and char in [' ','.',',','(',')',':','{','}'] and s:
            ret.append(s)
            s=''
            hashtag=False 

        if hashtag:
            s+=char

    if s:
        ret.append(s)

    return set(ret)
```