# Extracting a list of hashtags from a tweet in a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this [dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8i84o.png)

I'm trying to extract a list of hashtags from each tweet and map it to a new column called 'hashtags' in the DataFrame. However, the code I have tried so far just returns everything in the tweet after the hashtag, instead of a list of just the hashtags.

```
def extract_hashtags(df):
    df['hashtags'] = [x if x.startswith('#') else 'NaN' for x in df.Tweets]
    return df
```

Comment: This question can help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6331497/an-elegant-way-to-get-hashtags-out-of-a-string-in-python

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 're' module to find all instances of words that begin with #, like this..

```py
import re

def extract_hashtags(df):
    df['hashtags'] = [re.findall(r'#\w+', x) if re.findall(r'#\w+', x) else np.nan for x in df.Tweets]
    return df
```

Comment: Great !This returns the hashtags. However in the rows without hashtags it returns an empty list. I'd like it to return np.nan

Comment: try this: df['hashtags'] = [re.findall(r'#\w+', x) if re.findall(r'#\w+', x) else np.nan for x in df.Tweets]. This should work, and if it does il update my answer.